# Bookmarks Inconsistencies

Tags: c#, ms-word, bookmarks

I have tried to figure this out now for about 30 minutes to no avail.

I got this code:

```
class BookMarkTest
{
    Application word;
    Document doc;

    public BookMarkTest()
    {
        word = new Application();
        doc = word.Documents.Open("C:\\Users\\Vipar\\Desktop\\TestSkabelon.docx");
        Console.WriteLine("BEFORE:\n");
        foreach (Bookmark b in doc.Bookmarks)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}\n", b.Name);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}, Text: {1}\n", doc.Bookmarks[2].Name, doc.Bookmarks[2].Range.Text);
        test(ref doc);
        Console.WriteLine("------------------\n");
        Console.WriteLine("AFTER:\n");
        foreach (Bookmark b in doc.Bookmarks)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}\n", b.Name);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}, Text: {1}\n", doc.Bookmarks[2].Name, doc.Bookmarks[2].Range.Text);
        doc = null;
        word = null;
    }

    // Fixed the code so it replaces bookmarks correctly rather than removing them.
    public void test(ref Document doc)
    {
        Dictionary<string, Bookmark> bookmarks = new Dictionary<string, Bookmark>();
        foreach(Bookmark b in doc.Bookmarks) {
            bookmarks.Add(b.Name, b);
        }
        BookMarkReplaceNative(bookmarks["Titel"], "Min nye titel");
    }

    internal void BookMarkReplaceNative(Bookmark bookmark, string newText)
    {
        object rng = bookmark.Range;
        string name = bookmark.Name;

        bookmark.Range.Text = newText;
        doc.Bookmarks.Add(name, rng);
    }
}
```

First I check if all the bookmarks are there. There are 3 (I print them out to check this before I do anything else) so the array should be `0 = KontraktStart, 1 = Signatur, 2 = Titel` , but when I call `doc.Bookmarks[2].Name` I get `Signatur` rather than `Titel`. I can't figure out why that is. I have tried to do `doc.Bookmarks[3].Name` but that tells me the element doesn't exist. For some reason I can't call `doc.Bookmarks[0].Name` name though. It's like an element disappears and is replaced with nothing.

Also my `test()` method removes `Title` from the `Bookmarks` array entirely. I knew this would happen, but how do I go about just replacing the bookmark rather than completely remove it? When I look in my document I can see that the text on the specific bookmark actually changes, but the bookmark is removed which is not desired. **FIXED THIS. ADDED TO CODE SNIPPET**

So my question is two-fold:

1. How come elements are disappearing from the `Bookmarks` collection before I even manipulate the collection?
2. How do I replace a Bookmark rather than completely remove it? **FIXED THIS. ADDED TO CODE SNIPPET**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: some ideas from Word VBA point of view (again)... 1st. first bookmark has index 1 (not 0). 2nd. Bookmarks collection is sort alphabetically. 3rd. replacing bookmark range removes the bookmark- unfortunately it does it and we need to use additional techniques to replicate removed bookmark.

Comment: In the Bookmarks collection all of the 3 bookmarks are there. I checked this three or four times now through debugging. They are not missing. The index starts at 0 and ends at 2. But still when I call index 2 I get index 1 and when I call index 0 I am told it doesn't exist.